# Set value of radio button input using URL Parameter only (WITHOUT JQuery or JavaScript)

Tags: html, url, url-parameters

I have an HTML form on a web page. I want to send users an email with a URL that they can click to fill out the form. I want to pre-populate the value of a radio button group using URL parameters only.

The platform I am using does not allow me to do any scripting of any kind. I need to do this using **only** the URL parameters.

This is trivial for other types of input tags. For example, if I have a page called `form.html` and within that page I have an `input` tag as follows:

```
<input name="firstname" type="text">
```

Then I can use the following URL to pre-populate the field with the value "James":

```
http://form.html?firstname=James
```

What I am looking for is how to do this with a radio button. For example, let's say my page `form.html` has a radio button group with three options as follows:

```
<input name="status" type="radio" value="New">
<input name="status" type="radio" value="Expired">
<input name="status" type="radio" value="Renewed">
```

How do I pre-set the value of this radio button group with a URL parameter?

I have tried the following:

```
http://form.html?status=Expired
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any way to do this without JS or JQuery? You may think I can just set the value I want to be selected by default using the `checked=true` attribute in the HTML itself, but the problem is that the value I want to pre-populate is different depending on the user, so I need to set it in the URL parameter.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your example with prefilling inputs from query parameters. But you may be able to use a select instead of radio buttons

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmmagic.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely possible with a `<select>`but that's not the look my boss wants :(

Answer (score -2):

Came across this when looking for same answer and surprised no one answered it. Bit late but I figured this out and thought I'd put in answer here. Basically, I ran an pageload function and grabbed the parameters via URLSearchParams then selected the radio button via an ID. For example:

Add IDs to your radio buttons:

```
<input id="new" name="status" type="radio" value="New">
<input id="expired" name="status" type="radio" value="Expired">
<input id="renewed" name="status" type="radio" value="Renewed">
```

Then run the javascript below upon pageload (add if statements to handle different statuses):

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const status = urlParams.get('status'); 
if (status == "expired") {
 document.getElementById("expired").checked = true;
 }
```

I based this off the following answer but modified it for radio butons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267794/7901491

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but my original question clearly states "without using JQuery or JavaScript". I already know how to do it with JavaScript.